# Scala : Enumeration with special characters

Tags: scala, jvm

How to create and use an enumeration that have some special characters and spaces within its values ?

```
object Bots extends Enumeration {
  type Bots = Value
  val `apis-google`, `mediapartners-google`, `adsbot-google-mobile-apps`, `google favicon` = Value
}
```

When this enumeration is called, the special characters seems to be replaced by some internal identifiers or changed their encoding:

```
for (bot <- Bots.values) println(bot)
```

output:

> ```
> apis$minusgoogle 
> mediapartners$minusgoogle 
> adsbot$minusgoogle$minusmobile$minusapps 
> google$u0020favicon
> ```

EDIT : Im using scala 2.2

Comment: In general, `Enumeration` in **Scala 2** is rarely used. It would be simpler and easier to just use a sealed trait and a bunch of case objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change enumeration's naming behaviour by overriding [`Enumeration#Val#toString`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/d974e9960081eace9c54c7fddbd15d91ce4847a8/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L244)

```
scala> object Bots extends Enumeration {
     |   val `apis-google`
     |     , `mediapartners-google`
     |     , `adsbot-google-mobile-apps`
     |     , `google favicon` = new Val {
     |         override def toString() = 
     |           super.toString()
     |             .replace("$minus", "-")
     |             .replace("$u0020", " ")
     |       }
     | }
object Bots

scala> Bots.values.foreach(println)
apis-google
mediapartners-google
adsbot-google-mobile-apps
google favicon
```

or try enumeratum library

```
scala> import enumeratum._
     | 
     | sealed trait Bots extends EnumEntry
     | 
     | object Bots extends Enum[Bots] {
     |   val values = findValues
     | 
     |   case object `apis-google` extends Bots
     |   case object `mediapartners-google` extends Bots
     |   case object `adsbot-google-mobile-apps` extends Bots
     |   case object `google favicon` extends Bots
     | 
     | }
import enumeratum._
trait Bots
object Bots

scala> Bots.values.foreach(println)
apis-google
mediapartners-google
adsbot-google-mobile-apps
google favicon
```

or Scala 3

```
scala> enum Bots:                                                                                                                                             
     |   case `apis-google`, `mediapartners-google`, `adsbot-google-mobile-apps`, `google favicon`
     | 
// defined class Bots

scala> Bots.values.foreach(println)
apis-google
mediapartners-google
adsbot-google-mobile-apps
google favicon
```

Comment: Thank you ! I added the version to the question !

Answer (score 3):

```
$ scala
Starting scala3 REPL...
scala> object Bots extends Enumeration {                                                                                                                                                                           
     |   type Bots = Value
     |   val `apis-google`: Bots = Value(0, "apis-google")
     |   val `mediapartners-google`: Bots = Value(1, "mediapartners-google") 
     |   val `adsbot-google-mobile-apps`: Bots = Value(2, "adsbot-google-mobile-apps")
     |   val `google favicon`: Bots = Value(3, "google favicon")
     | }
     | 
// defined object Bots

scala> for (bot <- Bots.values) println(bot)                                                                                                                                                                       
     | 
apis-google
mediapartners-google
adsbot-google-mobile-apps
google favicon
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you can use `NameTransformer` object to encode your string. Problem is that enum is comparing string with name of enum which is scala symbol (so this name is encoded to build the name which is correct java name) in `withName` method.
Code looks like this:

```scala
  test("enum") {
    println(definitions.Countries.`United Kingdom`.toString())
    // prints United$u0020Kingdom
    val UK = definitions.Countries.withName(NameTransformer.encode("United Kingdom"))
    UK shouldBe definitions.Countries.`United Kingdom`
  }
```